# How to convert Number into Words in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I need to convert amount into words for example total = 5600 into five thousand six hundred only in yii2

Comment: Not sure about yii but you can use this custom function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314997/how-to-convert-amount-in-number-to-words

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - I was going to link something similar but then I saw that he only wanted it to work in yii2... ;-)

Comment: I found a yii1 extension. I have never used yii actually

Answer (score 1):

In case of using Yii2 you can do it as simple as the following:

see this [Doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asSpellout()-detail) reference.

You have to use formatter it will then format it according to your app's language